# Copy selected nodes to a new tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I'm trying to copy all selected nodes from one fancytree control to another one on the same page. So far I've tried the following code but the second tree remains blank:

```
        var sourceTree= $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
        var destinationTree= $("#destinationTree").fancytree("getTree");

        var selectedNodes = sourceTree.getSelectedNodes();
        var rootNode = destinationTree.rootNode;

        rootNode.addChildren(selectedNodes);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addChildren` expects a plain object, so you could try

```
$.each(sourceTree.getSelectedNodes(), function(idx, node){
    destinationTree.rootNode.addNode(node.toDict());
});
```

or

```
$.each(sourceTree.getSelectedNodes(), function(idx, node){
    node.copyTo(destinationTree.rootNode);
});
```

Comment: How can we copy all children as well?